# WKT number format inconsistent?

Tags: well-known-text

The [WKT specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) allows both period and comma to be the decimal separator in floating-point numbers (section 7.2.1):

> `<decimal point> ::=  <period> | <comma>`

However, a comma could result in ambiguous WKT representations.
In [this example](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html#id621310), the polygon is specified with five points, but the WKT could also be parsed as having three points:

```
POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))
```

I'm assuming that nobody deliberately uses `,` as decimal separator, but is that really true?

Is there any reason to try to parse numbers in WKT with `,`?
Or shouly I assume that the specification is just buggy?

Comment: in some locales it is perfectly normal to use , as decimal separator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Comment: But why should WKT representations be locale sensitive?

Comment: but why should they not?

Comment: Because you'd get ambiguities, as shown in the question.

Comment: I think the interpretation of white space removes those ambiguities, from a parsing perspective.

Comment: @L_Holcombe not in the example; `0,0` and `1,1` could be valid numbers

Comment: Your first point could be (0 0.0) - but then what's your second point? (0 0,0, 1,1 1,1, 0,0 0) is how the interpreter would expect to read three xy point values.

Comment: @L_Holcombe Yes, I overlooked the

Comment: [sorry] Yes, I overlooked that coordinate pairs must be separated with a comma; please make this an answer. (But where does the specification allow to put whitespace between numbers? It's obvious from the examples, but they forgot to put it into the grammar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the coordinate pairs must be separated with a comma, and whitespace is treated as a separator between numbers in a coordinate pair, such ambiguities can be easily worked out by the parser.

(I personally think this is an example of something that could and should be internationally standardized - but then again, I'm also an American who has trouble with the metric system.)

Answer (score 1):

```
POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))
```

is not ambiguous, because the number of values for a point cannot be 3 (that would be POLYGON M or POLYGON Z).

That said, at least SpatiaLite doesn't support comma as a decimal separator. I didn't try other applications.